# Using php array in javascript to populate a 'select' ajax

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, ajax

I have a multidimensional array of stores and states, which makes a json as follows:

```
<?php 
$list[$store][$state] = $city;

echo json_encode ($list);
{"store 1": {"state x": "city 1", "state y": "city 2"}, "store 2": {"state z": "city 3"}}
?>
```

I need to create a select that changes the second select according to what was chosen, using the data of the array in question.
Something like this http://www.daviferreira.com/blog/exemplos/cidades/index.php

How can I handle this data in php for javascript?
And how can I separate them to use them in each select?

I've already tried:

```
var list = JSON.parse ("<? php echo json_encode($list)?>");
```

But it did not work :(

**EDIT** The structure of the selects should look like this.

```
{"store 1": {"state x": "city 1", "state y": "city 2"}, "store 2": {"state z": "city 3"}}

First select
Store 1
Store 2

if store 1 selected
Second select
State x
State y

if store 2 selected
Second select
State z
```

Something like that

Comment: You don't need `JSON.parse`. Just write `var list = <?php echo json_encode($list); ?>;`

Comment: Do you want `list` to change dynamically? PHP runs on the server when the page is first created, not on the client. If you want to update dynamically you need to use AJAX to get a new list.

Comment: He needs `JSON.parse` in order to convert the string to an array

Comment: @x3ns No, because the output of `json_encode()` is a Javascript literal.

Comment: Ahh you're right, my bad

Comment: @Barmar Yes, i know. But i need to separate the json objects before doing this.

Comment: What do you mean by separate the json objects? Can't you do that in JS using the `list` variable?

Comment: sounds like you need a loop which will use the data to create the options for the selects

Comment: There are many questions about implementing cascading menus like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do this using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var list = <?= json_encode($list); ?>;
    var storeSelect = $("<select></select>");   
    storeSelect.attr('id', 'storeSelect');
    for(var item in list)
    {
        storeSelect.append('<option value="' + item + '">' + item + '</option>');
    }
    $('#theForm').append(storeSelect);


    var storeStates = $("<select></select>");
    storeStates.attr('id', 'storeState');       
    $('#theForm').append(storeStates);  

    $('#storeSelect').change(function ()
    {
        var storeName = $(this).val();
        for(var item in list[storeName])
        {   
            storeStates.html('<option value="' + item + '">' + item + '</option>');
        }   
    });
    $('#storeSelect').change();
});
```

It simply uses loops to create the select menu. And uses the `onChange` event to manipulate the values.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it using jQuery. If you're using plain JS, converting it is an exercise for the reader.

```
var list = <?php echo json_encode($list); ?>;
$.each(list, function(store) {
    $("#store_menu").append($("<option>", {
        value: store,
        text: store
    }));
});

$("#store_menu").change(function() {
    var store = $(this).val();
    $("#state_menu").empty();
    $.each(list[store], function(state) {
        $("#state_menu").append($("<option>", {
            value: state,
            text: state
        }));
    });
});
```

Comment: You have invalid syntax at `$("#state_menu").append($("<option>", {`, it should be `$("<option>")`. The bracket is not closed.

Comment: @mega6382 Thanks, fixed. The parenthesis is closed after the object with the attributes.